# IOS8 Swift JSON

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to retrieve values from an array that I get from a JSON web request

I have the following JSON response:

```
{
    diskspace1 = "250.888515";
    diskspace2 = "250.888515";
    "have_warnings" = 0;
    jobs =     (
                {
            filename = test;
            id = "SABnzbd_nzo_LQ6Og5";
            mb = "428.812928";
            mbleft = "388.87428";
            msgid = "";
            timeleft = "0:00:00";
        },
                {
            filename = tt;
            id = "SABnzbd_nzo_ESYJ5N";
            mb = "5041.869138";
            mbleft = "4399.935587";
            msgid = "";
            timeleft = "0:00:00";
        }
    );
    kbpersec = 0;
    loadavg = "1.15 | 1.09 | 1.10 | V=1270M R=106M";
    mb = 0;
    mbleft = 0;
    noofslots = 2;
    "pause_int" = 0;
    paused = 0;
    "pp_active" = 0;
    speed = "0 ";
    state = IDLE;
    timeleft = "0:00:00";
}
```

With this code i can print the "Jobs" section from my JSON.

```
    func searchApps(escapedSearchTerm: String) {

    // Here iTunes API wants multiple terms separated by + symbols, so replace spaces with + signs
    var appSearchTerm = searchTerm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)

    // Now escape anything else that isn't URL-friendly
    var escapedSearchTerm = appSearchTerm.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var urlPath = ""

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if(error) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        println("my Data is \(jsonResult)")
        if(err?) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        var results: NSArray = jsonResult["jobs"] as NSArray
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableData = results
            self.appsTable.reloadData()
            })
        })
    task.resume()
}
```

And now to my problem.

How do i print the diskspace1 and diskspace2 value from my JSON???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get the diskspace1 and diskspace2 value from my JSON is by

```
jsonResult["diskspace1"]
jsonResult["diskspace2"]
```

Use the following code to print the diskspace1 and diskspace2 value

```
var diskSpace1 = jsonResult["diskspace1"]
println(diskSpace1)
var diskSpace2 = jsonResult["diskspace2"]
println(diskSpace2)
```

for more information to access the collection types refer [collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_165)

Comment: That was easy. Thanks